# How to set scope of manifest to the subdomains

Tags: subdomain, progressive-web-apps, manifest

I have an application that contains different projects.
I have an SSR project that developed with jquery and served with django template at the https://example.com
and I have some other applications with React that exist in the sub-domain of that, e.g :
https://test1.example.com
https://test2.example.com
now I want to convert my applications to one PWA, I convert the main one ( https://example.com ) to PWA but when it redirect to one sub-domain project, it get out of PWA standlone view and the navigator bar display.
how should I fix that that I can have all of that in one PWA? is there any related to scope of manifest or what?